# SQL Local Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I was writing a SQL script and suddenly got confused at the following line:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT @IDTTIC = IDTTIC TOP 1 * FROM @ProblemTickets)
```

where `@ProblemTickets` is my table variable.

Is the above condition well written or should it be like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 @IDTTIC = IDTTIC FROM @ProbelmTickets)
```

Comment: That should be easy for you to test, isn't it?

Comment: Neither is legal syntax. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why are you using TOP without ORDER BY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM @ProblemTickets)
  BEGIN
     SELECT TOP 1 @IDTTIC = IDTTIC FROM @ProblemTickets
  END
```

The Exists Clause check for exisitance of something, if it does exist it will return true and if it doesnt it will return false but you cant return data inside the Exists clause.

You can try like I have shown above

> 1- Check for existance of something 1st.
>
> 2- If it exists then get the top 1 value in your variable.

**Suggestion by Aaron Bertrand **

You can simply assign a value to your variable without checking for existence 1st, If there is any data in the table the value will be assigned to the variable otherwise variable remains NULL.

When assigning value to a variable in a SELECT statement make sure your SELECT is returning only one row back if which obviously you are already doing SELECT TOP 1 but to get the “Right TOP 1” row you should use ORDER BY clause as well. 
Also when assigning values to variable in SELECT you cannot retrieve data at the same time, If SELECT is returning more than one column all the values retuned should be stored in a variable

Something like this ..

```
SELECT TOP 1 @Var1 = Col1,  @Var2 = Col2, @Var3 = Col3
FROM TABLE_Name
ORDER BY Some_Column
```

You Cannot do something like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 @Var1 = Col1,  @Var2 = Col2,  Col3
FROM TABLE_Name
ORDER BY Some_Column
```

Comment: Why are you introducing EXISTS here? If there are no rows, the assignment will lead to the variable being NULL, just like if you only assign the variable if the EXISTS is true. Seems like extra code for no purpose.

Comment: @AaronBertrand are you going through all of my answers ?? :) OP was trying to check for existance and assiging the value to a variable at the same time, I just split it into two statements. assuming this is just a snippet of his code, and actual code would have a lot more ifs and else.

Comment: My point was that you could show a better way to do what the question explicitly asked for - there is no reason to select from the table twice.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Point taken I have update my answer, and thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it should just be:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @IDTTIC = IDTTIC FROM @ProblemTickets ORDER BY <something>;
```

If there are any rows in the table, the value will be populated (unless that column can be NULL, of course). If there are no rows, the variable will still be NULL.

There is no need to say `IF EXISTS` and *then* assign the variable with another `SELECT`. You are just reading the table twice instead of once for no good reason.